# Error "No such container sandbox-hdp" when trying to install docker image on RHEL7

Tags: docker, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to get the HDP sandbox running on RHEL7. I am however getting "no such container sandbox-hdp" error message when I try to run docker-deploy-hdp30.sh.

```
sudo sh docker-deploy-hdp30.sh


+ registry=hortonworks
+ name=sandbox-hdp
+ version=3.0.1
+ proxyName=sandbox-proxy
+ proxyVersion=1.0
+ flavor=hdp
+ echo hdp
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.d
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.stream.d
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
3.0.1: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
70799bbf2226: Pull complete
40963917cdad: Pull complete
3fe9adbb8d7e: Pull complete
ee3ec4e8cb3d: Pull complete
7ea5917732c0: Pull complete
2d951411620c: Pull complete
f4c5e354e7fd: Pull complete
22ffa6ef360f: Pull complete
2060aa0f3751: Pull complete
ca01ba34744d: Pull complete
83326dded077: Pull complete
eb3d71b90b73: Pull complete
bdd1cab41c81: Pull complete
500cc770c4bd: Pull complete
0cb1decd5474: Pull complete
b9591f4b6855: Pull complete
f28e56086127: Pull complete
e7de4e7d0bca: Pull complete
ec77967d2166: Pull complete
4fdcae170114: Pull complete
6347f5df8ffc: Pull complete
6a6ecc232709: Pull complete
ea845898ff50: Downloading [==================================================>] 2.2GB/2.2GB
02135573b1bf: Download complete
cb0176867cd8: Download complete
3c08321268fd: Download complete
82e82a97c465: Downloading [==================================================>] 6.405GB/6.405GB
8aaaa48ed101: Download complete
74b321ac2ac5: Download complete
569da02c0a66: Download complete
af40820407ef: Downloading [==================================================>] 11.37GB/11.37GB
write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob635285518: no space left on device
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
1.0: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-proxy
951bdea65c93: Pull complete
4b9047c5fbbb: Pull complete
773156407aae: Pull complete
d8524176841d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:42e4cfbcbb76af07e5d8f47a183a0d4105e65a1e7ef39fe37ab746e8b2523e9e
Status: Downloaded newer image for hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
+ '[' hdp == hdf ']'
+ '[' hdp == hdp ']'
+ hostname=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com
++ docker images
++ grep hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ version=
+ docker network create cda
18f248ed47236cdaca73c1664fdc13b193a8224a714a5e6788481002d7f8e787
+ docker run --privileged --name sandbox-hdp -h sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com --network=cda --network-alias=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -d hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
+ echo ' Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait'
Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait
+ sleep 2
+ docker exec -t sandbox-hdp sh -c 'rm -rf /var/run/postgresql/*; systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service;'
Error: No such container: sandbox-hdp
+ sed s/sandbox-hdp-security/sandbox-hdp/g assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ mv -f assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh.new assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ chmod +x assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ uname
+ grep MINGW
+ chmod +x sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
+ sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
9434d4eea27290ea8417b2be653ccf574fe60035f964cddc3eac0a77daf89805
```

In there is a "docker: invalid reference format." error message. I am running docker CE:

```
Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77156
```

Update:  I missed the disk space error in the above error message.   I had the /var/lib/docker created as a new mount with loads of space free.

Then I go disk space errors when the script tried to create a /hadoop/hdfs folder.  So I had a new mount created at /hadoop.  But I am still getting disk space errors.

Disk space can be seen here.

[image: Available disk space]

Error now:

```
+ registry=hortonworks

+ name=sandbox-hdp

+ version=3.0.1

+ proxyName=sandbox-proxy

+ proxyVersion=1.0

+ flavor=hdp

+ echo hdp

+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.d

+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.stream.d

+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1

3.0.1: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-hdp

70799bbf2226: Pull complete

40963917cdad: Pull complete

3fe9adbb8d7e: Pull complete

ee3ec4e8cb3d: Pull complete

7ea5917732c0: Pull complete

2d951411620c: Pull complete

f4c5e354e7fd: Pull complete

22ffa6ef360f: Pull complete

2060aa0f3751: Pull complete

ca01ba34744d: Pull complete

83326dded077: Pull complete

eb3d71b90b73: Pull complete

bdd1cab41c81: Pull complete

500cc770c4bd: Pull complete

0cb1decd5474: Pull complete

b9591f4b6855: Pull complete

f28e56086127: Pull complete

e7de4e7d0bca: Pull complete

ec77967d2166: Pull complete

4fdcae170114: Pull complete

6347f5df8ffc: Pull complete

6a6ecc232709: Pull complete

ea845898ff50: Pull complete

02135573b1bf: Pull complete

cb0176867cd8: Pull complete

3c08321268fd: Pull complete

82e82a97c465: Pull complete

8aaaa48ed101: Pull complete

74b321ac2ac5: Pull complete

569da02c0a66: Pull complete

af40820407ef: Extracting [==================================================>] 11.37GB/11.37GB

failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: write /hadoop/hdfs/data/current/BP-1419118625-172.17.0.2-1543512323726/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir1/blk_1073742280: no space left on device

+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0

1.0: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-proxy

Digest: sha256:42e4cfbcbb76af07e5d8f47a183a0d4105e65a1e7ef39fe37ab746e8b2523e9e

Status: Image is up to date for hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0

+ '[' hdp == hdf ']'

+ '[' hdp == hdp ']'

+ hostname=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com

++ docker images

++ awk '{print $2}'

++ grep hortonworks/sandbox-hdp

+ version=

+ docker network create cda

+ docker run --privileged --name sandbox-hdp -h sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com --network=cda --network-alias=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -d hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:

docker: invalid reference format.

See 'docker run --help'.

+ echo ' Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait'

Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait

+ sleep 2

+ docker exec -t sandbox-hdp sh -c 'rm -rf /var/run/postgresql/*; systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service;'

Error: No such container: sandbox-hdp

+ sed s/sandbox-hdp-security/sandbox-hdp/g assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh

+ mv -f assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh.new assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh

+ chmod +x assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh

+ assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh

+ uname

+ grep MINGW

+ chmod +x sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh

+ sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
```

I draw attention to:

```
 failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: write /hadoop/hdfs/data/current/BP-1419118625-172.17.0.2-1543512323726/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir1/blk_1073742280: no space left on device
```

Edit:  iNode usage below:

[image]

Comment: `write /var/lib/docker/...: no space left on device` is going to be your first biggest issue, and that's definitely not a code-related problem.

Comment: Thanks, missed that one!!

Answer (score 0):

Docker engine uses /var/lib/docker to store images and container runtime environment. HDP 3.0 sandbox is a huge image around ~20GB. Please try to clean up older unused docker images and make space in Docker host's local storage area and try.

One option is to remove unused containers and images using `docker system prune` or selected images using `docker rmi <image ID>`.

Comment: Thanks - how can I change the docker image location and transfer all images?  Is using a symlink to a mounted folder, within the /var folder the best way?

Comment: you could probably customize the storage directory on a linux host by editing the docker config file

Comment: Hi,  I updated the question above with more information.  I had more space added to the server, with a few additional mount points, now getting a different error.

Comment: You may have to check if you have exhausted your inodes by running `df -i`. Also, check from your docker config if you are using overlay2 storage driver which is  efficient in terms of inode utilization.

Comment: I am using devicemapper if I recall.  What’s an inode?!

Comment: I added an image of the inode usage to the main question.   Its a brand new server and mounted volume.