# Fail launching docker-deploy-hdp30.sh with Error: No such container: sandbox-hdp

Tags: docker, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to use docker hortonworks sandbox on MacOS

I follow this tutorial:
https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/3.html

I adjuted the dedicated memory according to the documentation to 14 GB of RAM

> Select the Advanced tab and adjust the dedicated memory to at least
> 12GB of RAM.

When I launch the script as mentionned in the tuto:

> In the decompressed folder, you will find shell script
> docker-deploy-.sh. From the command line, Linux / Mac / Windows(Git
> Bash), run the script:

```
cd /path/to/script
sh docker-deploy-{HDPversion}.sh
```

I get the following logs containing the error

```
tester@Mac-mini-de-tester HDP_3.0.1_docker-deploy-scripts_18120587fc7fb % sh docker-deploy-hdp30.sh
+ registry=hortonworks
+ name=sandbox-hdp
+ version=3.0.1
+ proxyName=sandbox-proxy
+ proxyVersion=1.0
+ flavor=hdp
+ echo hdp
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.d
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.stream.d
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
3.0.1: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
70799bbf2226: Pull complete 
40963917cdad: Pull complete 
3fe9adbb8d7e: Pull complete 
ee3ec4e8cb3d: Pull complete 
7ea5917732c0: Pull complete 
2d951411620c: Pull complete 
f4c5e354e7fd: Pull complete 
22ffa6ef360f: Pull complete 
2060aa0f3751: Pull complete 
ca01ba34744d: Pull complete 
83326dded077: Pull complete 
eb3d71b90b73: Pull complete 
bdd1cab41c81: Pull complete 
500cc770c4bd: Pull complete 
0cb1decd5474: Pull complete 
b9591f4b6855: Pull complete 
f28e56086127: Pull complete 
e7de4e7d0bca: Pull complete 
ec77967d2166: Pull complete 
4fdcae170114: Pull complete 
6347f5df8ffc: Pull complete 
6a6ecc232709: Pull complete 
ea845898ff50: Pull complete 
02135573b1bf: Pull complete 
cb0176867cd8: Pull complete 
3c08321268fd: Pull complete 
82e82a97c465: Pull complete 
8aaaa48ed101: Pull complete 
74b321ac2ac5: Pull complete 
569da02c0a66: Pull complete 
af40820407ef: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:7b767af7b42030fb1dd0f672b801199241e6bef1258e3ce57361edb779d95921
Status: Downloaded newer image for hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
docker.io/hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
1.0: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-proxy
951bdea65c93: Pull complete 
4b9047c5fbbb: Pull complete 
773156407aae: Pull complete 
d8524176841d: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:42e4cfbcbb76af07e5d8f47a183a0d4105e65a1e7ef39fe37ab746e8b2523e9e
Status: Downloaded newer image for hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
docker.io/hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
+ '[' hdp == hdf ']'
+ '[' hdp == hdp ']'
+ hostname=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com
++ docker images
++ grep hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ version='3.0.1
latest'
+ docker network create cda
ec09d0d2e9f79122fd6efd45fb51c4bdd4cd78e41347dcb4e74d08f7b9a889e1
+ docker run --privileged --name sandbox-hdp -h sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com --network=cda --network-alias=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -d 'hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
latest'
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
+ echo ' Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait'
 Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait
+ sleep 2
+ docker exec -t sandbox-hdp sh -c 'rm -rf /var/run/postgresql/*; systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service;'
Error: No such container: sandbox-hdp
+ sed s/sandbox-hdp-security/sandbox-hdp/g assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ mv -f assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh.new assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ chmod +x assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ uname
+ grep MINGW
+ chmod +x sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
+ sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
5357ab1b2242cdc5adba835206db0ca9024b7d984acd79b4d59f30052e93e84e
```

I found the following link with the same problem, but in my case I dont have the problem of:

```
write /var/lib/docker/...: no space left on device
```

[Error "No such container sandbox-hdp" when trying to install docker image on RHEL7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676401/error-no-such-container-sandbox-hdp-when-trying-to-install-docker-image-on-rhe)

Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the docker run command - the image name specified has an unwanted `latest` at end of the command

```
docker run --privileged --name sandbox-hdp -h sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com --network=cda --network-alias=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -d 'hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1 latest'
```

probably if you can change it to below format and try running it, might fix it.

```
docker run --privileged --name sandbox-hdp -h sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com --network=cda --network-alias=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -d hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1 latest
```

note: I have only removed the quotes as 'latest' might be an argument to the container...